# What Torah portions are read on Monday and Thursday?

Tags: torah-reading

I daaven at home. Do I read half of the week's torah portion on Monday and half of it on Thursday, and then the whole thing on Saturday? Or is it just the first few parshas read on Mon and repeated on Thurs?

Comment: Only a small section is read on Mon/Thurs in synagogue (often found at the back of a siddur). Also, since it was set to be read in public on those days (http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/115,2471124/Why-were-Torah-readings-established-for-Mondays-and-Thursdays.html) why would you use those days as a guide for reading in private? If you are studying it, then you should be doing that throughout the week.

Answer (score 2):

Public reading of the Torah can only be done in the presence of a minyan. (I will edit in a source for this, a bit later.) Thus, when at home, by yourself, you would not read the weekly parsha in the manner that they do with a minyan.

When the portion is read on Monday and Thursday as well as Shabbat afternoon, generally, only the first section until *Sheini* is read. There are some exceptions to this, and many siddurim would show you exactly what is read for each weekly parsha (Art Scroll is one such siddur.) It is the same reading for Monday, Thursday and Shabbat afternoon unless some other holiday pre-empts the weekday reading.